# One or more plugins require a higher Android SDK version

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle

One or more plugins require a higher Android SDK version.
Fix this issue by adding the following to C:\Users\AndroidStudioProjects\android\app\build.gradle:
android {
compileSdkVersion 33
...
}
If anyone know the solution, please help me with this.

This is my build.gradle file :

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.clima"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}
```

Comment: Your file location is `project > build.gradle`, it is not `project > android > app > build.gradle`, check again

Answer (score 0):

Understand the Android Project Hierarchy in Flutter based projects. So there are 2 build.gradle files

App Level > One inside android>app>build.gradle and

Android Level > Other one inside android>build.gradle

To modify parameters like compileSdkVersion got to App Level gradle file and modify it to the required versions

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
```

If you have default sdkVersion like

```
compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
```

Replace it to

```
compileSdkVersion 33
```

[image]